# Split a string in semantic MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates, semantic-mediawiki

I want to add a link using existing string in in my wiki page. 
This string will be appended to a url to form a complete URL.

This string consists of many words, for example "Crisis Management in International Computing"

I want to split by empty space " " then construct this string: "Crisis+Management+in+International+Computing"

Here is the String variable I have in my wiki page:

```
{{SUBJECTPAGENAME}}
```

Note: I have to check first if the string consists of more than one word, as if the string is just one word like this "Crisis" I won't perform split function.

I searched the web and did not find clear semantic to us in order to perform this issue.

Anyone experienced such a matter?

Comment: What do you use the splitted string for? Or do you just want to replace spaces with `+`

Comment: I have a service running in another (external) server, that service takes some string in the url from the source server. So , a url will be placed in server A , that url points to a service in server B. And i have a string in server A which I need to append to that service url. Etc: www.xyz.com/this+is+a+string          The text after the slash is a string in this format "this is a string". I just need to split any string of this type by empty string " " and add it to the url separated by + .  I hope this explains it further.

Comment: Why can't you just search and replace all spaces with `+`?

Comment: This what I am aiming/asking for Mr. @leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to go for a custom parser function.

Or as a hack, try splitting the string using the **arraymaptemplate** parser functions coming as part of [Semantic Forms](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms).

URL : [arraymaptemplate](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms/Semantic_Forms_and_templates#arraymaptemplate) parser function.

You can use an intro template to create the link and  use array template to split and add the words to the intro template.

I have not tried it with delimiter character as space, but from the documentation, seems, it should be working using the html encoding for space.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly from the comments, you want to replace all occurrences of space in your string, and replace it with `+`. That can be done with string functions of the [ParserFunctions extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions).

If you are running a fairly recent version of MediaWiki (>1.18, check by going to Special:Version), the ParserFunctions extension is bundled with the software. You just need to enable it by adding the following to `LocalSettings.php`:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/ParserFunctions/ParserFunctions.php";
$wgPFEnableStringFunctions = true;
```

Then you will be able to write e.g.

```
{{#replace: {{SUBJECTPAGENAME}} |<nowiki> </nowiki>|+}}
```

**Note however that if all you really want is a url version of a page name, you can just use `{{SUBJECTPAGENAMEE}}` instead of `{{SUBJECTPAGENAME}}`.**